# Remove tax info from cart page in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, tax

I have added tax rules for California state in my magento store. If the shipping is in california then the tax will be applied on total cart amount, for all other states the tax will not be applied on cart.
My problem is when I add a product in cart, It displays the tax details by default. When I select State other than California and click on Get a Quote in Estimate Shipping & Tax section, only then it removes the tax details from cart.
I want that, by default, there will be no tax details in cart page. When a customer selects State as California and Click on Get a Quote, only then it will display the tax details on cart total.
I have gone through this [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/31474/) where they say that its a Bug in Magento.
Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should be changeable. You can change the "default behaviour" here:

```
System > Config > Tax > Default Tax Destination Calculation > Default Country/State
```